# Why is if statement not working in ElementTree parsing?

Tags: python, xml, if-statement, xml-parsing, elementtree

I'm trying to parse an `xml` file using `ElementTree` which looks like this:

```xml
<Game>
  <Event timestamp="2016-08-14T14:23:33.634" id="1713385925" 
         version="1471181110290" last_modified="2016-08-14T14:25:11" y="11.0" 
         x="89.7" outcome="0" team_id="148" player_id="51327" sec="8" min="23" 
         period_id="1" type_id="4" event_id="205">

    <Q id="733814222" qualifier_id="265"/>
    <Q id="481660420" qualifier_id="286"/>
    <Q id="813378778" qualifier_id="152"/>
    <Q id="570443899" qualifier_id="56" value="Right"/>
    <Q id="420312891" qualifier_id="233" value="248"/>
    <Q id="1186861264" qualifier_id="13"/>
  </Event>

  <Event timestamp="2016-08-14T14:23:33.634" id="1635888622" 
         version="1471181110289" last_modified="2016-08-14T14:25:11" y="89.0" 
         x="10.3" outcome="1" team_id="143" player_id="169007" sec="8" min="23" 
         period_id="1" type_id="4" event_id="248">

    <Q id="1871787686" qualifier_id="56" value="Back"/>
    <Q id="176295814" qualifier_id="13"/>
    <Q id="69346842" qualifier_id="233" value="205"/>
    <Q id="1588029344" qualifier_id="265"/>
    <Q id="559785299" qualifier_id="285"/>
    <Q id="380723313" qualifier_id="152"/>
  </Event>
</Game>
```

The code I'm using is simple and is working as expected. However, everything changes when I try to add an `if condition` to the code

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root = ET.parse(r'C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\Abhishek\PSG - Copy\Sample.xml').getroot()

Games = root.getchildren()
for Game in Games:
    Events = Game.getchildren()
    for Event in Events:
        type_id = Event.attrib["type_id"]
        team_id = Event.attrib["team_id"]
        Qualifiers = Event.getchildren()
        for Qualifier in Qualifiers:
            id_ = Qualifier.attrib['id']
            if id_ == 142:
                print ("val")
```

Here's the error it's producing:

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\PSGPossessionSequences.py", line 9
    Games = root.getchildren()
DeprecationWarning: This method will be removed in future versions.  Use 'list(elem)' or iteration over elem instead.

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\PSGPossessionSequences.py", line 11
    Events = Game.getchildren()
DeprecationWarning: This method will be removed in future versions.  Use 'list(elem)' or iteration over elem instead.

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\PSGPossessionSequences.py", line 15
    Qualifiers = Event.getchildren()
DeprecationWarning: This method will be removed in future versions.  Use 'list(elem)' or iteration over elem instead.
```

I have tried removing the `if statement` and that works perfectly. However, I do need to set a condition to call all the `id_`s which are a certain value. I've tried using `"142"` as well as `142` but the problem persists. Why exactly is this happening?

Comment: Those are not errors, those are **warnings**. Did you read what they are telling you? You can trivially fix your code to follow the advice.

Comment: Also, XML attributes are not integers, but strings. You are asking Python to see if a string value is equal to an integer, and that's never going to be true (Python doesn't convert between strings and integers implicitly).

Comment: I realized they're warnings. However, a) How do I get the children tags without using `getchildren` and b) If the problem was solely that `getchildren` has been deprecated, why would the code give me correct outputs when the `if statement` has been removed?

Comment: The two are not related, your if test is just incorrect.

Comment: I've mentioned within the question itself that I've tried using "142" but it still shows the same warning

Comment: Yes, because the two are **not related**. The warnings and the `if` test are two separate things.

Comment: I do not understand. If they're just warnings and can be ignored, shouldn't I get some result for "142" because there are ids with value 142? Also, how I do work around not using get.children() if that's what's causing the warnins?

Comment: Just loop over the elements directly.

Comment: And where are you seeing an id of 142? The sample you posted in your question has no such element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The errors you see are not errors, but [warnings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html). You can ignore them, silence them, or fix your code by not using `.getchildren()`; you can iterate directly over each XML element instead:

```
root = ET.parse(r'C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\Abhishek\PSG - Copy\Sample.xml').getroot()

for Game in root:
    for Event in Game:
        # ...
        for Qualifier in Event:
```

The `if` test doesn't work because XML attributes are *strings*, text, not integer values. Test for a string:

```
if id_ == "142":
    print("val")
```

You may want to use [XPath queries](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#elementtree-xpath) instead of looping over everything. The base `ElementTree` implementation that comes with Python is a little limited though. You would get a far more powerful implementation if you installed the [lxml library](https://lxml.de/index.html), its [XPath support](https://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html) is far superior:

```
from lxml import etree as ET

document = ET.parse(r'C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\Abhishek\PSG - Copy\Sample.xml')
root = document.getroot()

qualifier = root.xpath(".//Event/Q[@id='142']")[0]
event = qualifier.getparent()
type_id = event.attrib["type_id"]
team_id = event.attrib["team_id"]
```

Answer (score 5):

Its a warning the getchildren() method is depreciated. Here is how to get the children now without the warning

```
def goddamnit_what_are_my_kids_called(self, element):
    for child in list(element):
        print(child.tag)
```

Comment: Please add some statements describing how how the given solution fixes the issue mentioned in the question. Only providing the code may not let the questioner completely understand how the issue is resolved.